# display user selected text in html popup and update it in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a background script which is fired upon clicking of chrome icon:

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    console.log("chrome.browserAction.onClicked...." + tab);
    var openSeleniumEditor = window.open(
        chrome.extension.getURL("Editor.html"),
        "Words Misspelled",
        "width=600,height=400"
    );
});
```

My target is to collect all the words in the article which needs correction. User selects the text from the current page and content script should collect that and append to the list in the editor. The Editor.html is always open unlike the normal pop up. When user closes this Editor.html the text from Editor.html should be saved to local storage so that it can be referred later.

content.js:

```
function getSelectedParagraphText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
      selection = document.selection.createRange();
  }
  var parent = selection.anchorNode;
  while (parent != null && parent.localName != "P") {
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  if (parent == null) {
    return "";
  } else {
    return parent.innerText || parent.textContent;
  }
}
```

Editor.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="Editor.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { width: 300px; }
      textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text"> </textarea>

  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to keep the code of Editor.html/Editor.js in a separate folder so that i can make use of it in every browser. Now how do i call/update the Editor.js or Editor.html to append the user selected text from content.js ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem here. The script inside editor.js can add chrome.runtime.onMessage listener, the background script can check if the editor window is open with chrome.tabs.query, and send messages with chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: sorry , i want to send the text from content.js to editor.js